# Simplifying an interface declaration the C++03 way

Tags: c++

As a way to reduce the busy work of copy/pasting the same code, I turned to the dark side and used a macro to do it for me.

Keep in mind the production code this is from is much larger and the task much more painful without macros like this to help. Specifically, it's a mix of static and virtual functions driven by a single string.

Now I know macros can get you into trouble, and using them this way is pretty 'stinky', so I want something better, but I'm having trouble coming up with something as easy and concise as this:

```
#define LAZY(name)\
   static const char * identify() { return name; }\
   virtual const char * getName() { return identify(); }

class A{
public:
   LAZY("class A")

   void foo(){
      std::cout << getName() << std::endl;
   }
};

class B: public A{
public:
   LAZY("class B")
};

std::string somevar( B::identify() );

int main(void){
   B b1;
   B.foo();
}
```

Some of the other approachs I took (and why they failed), are below:

```
template<class T>
class Base{
public:
   virtual const char * getName(){ return T::identify(); }

   // All other functions driven by string. IE:
   static void register(){ someFactory::reg( T::identify() ); }
   virtual unsigned int getHash(){ return someHashFoo( T::identify() ); }
};

class A: public Base<A> {
public:
   static const char * idenfity(){ return "class A"; }

   void foo(){ std::cout << getname() << std::endl; }
};

class B: public A, public Base<B> {
  // Conflict due to multi-inheritance.
};
```

Another failed approach due to wasting memory per instance, and a little complex:

```
class FaceBase{
public:
   virtual const char * getName() =0;
};

template<class T>
class ImplBase: public FaceBase {
public:
   virtual const char * getName(){ return T::identify(); }
};

class A{
public:
   FaceBase & common;

   static const char * identify(){ return "class A"; }

   A(): common(ImplBase<A>()){}

   virtual void foo(){ std::cout << common.getName() << std::endl; }
};

class B: public A{
   static const char * identify(){ return "class B"; }

   B(){ common = ImplBase<B>(); }
};
```

Comment: Why do you need this "class name" system in the first place? What's wrong with `typeid`?

Comment: That name could be anything, not just "class A". Type ID typically name mangles as a well, and wouldn't be consistent across platforms.

Comment: Sure, but what is the name used for, except identify a class?

Comment: The actual use-case is that the string is displayed to the user. However, there are other types of similar macros in the full project, that use symbols and not strings as arguments, to similar effect (driving a bunch of static data functions). So focusing on 'why a string' isn't as important as how to avoid boiler plate or wasteful memory allocation.

Comment: To clarify: `type_info::name` *may* return a mangled name, but that's an implementation detail anyway, since the interesting bit is `operator==`.

Comment: You might be able to get your second scheme to work with virtual inheritance. But it would be some work and would probably end up messier than the macro solution anyway, so I think your way is most likely the best.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You didn't actually ask any question, but under the assumption that it is, "How can I do this in a clean way without macros?", and further assuming that the "much larger" task you're referring to is a full custom RTTI system, the answer is, "You can't."

Every big project that does this kind of thing that I know of (MFC, Qt, LLVM) does one of these:

- Use macros. (MFC and to some extent Qt)
- Use a custom code generator. (Qt and to some extent LLVM)
- Write the boilerplate code. (LLVM)

Comment: "so I want something better, but I'm having trouble coming up with something ...". I was partly inspired by MFC and Qt, good catch.

Comment: rest easy, it's a common and GOOD practice. Don't be mislead by the general "avoid marcos" stuff, look at the causes and you can see that none of the bad factors apply here. Unlike all of the good ones.

Comment: I disagree that none of the bad factors apply here, but that's irrelevant anyway. The preprocessor should be your last resort when something isn't reasonably doable otherwise, but this is such a case. It doesn't matter how many problems the preprocessor has when the alternatives are even worse.